# Apply CSS for n-items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html structure as below

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

How can I apply styles for like the first 2 items one style and succeeding 2 another style? The 2 divs after the 4th one will have the same styles as 1st two and the patterns goes on.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use classes? Can the list contain unlimited divs?

Comment: You can use `#container div:nth-child(4n+1), #container div:nth-child(4n+2)` for the first style. 4n+3 and 4n for the other style. https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#structural-pseudos

Comment: @Dejan.S the html is auto generated from an npm package. I cant add classes to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @Chris G as well, you can use a `:nth-child(4n + k)` selector:

```css
div:nth-child(4n + 1), div:nth-child(4n + 2)  {
  color: green;
}

div:nth-child(4n + 3), div:nth-child(4n) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
<div>F</div>
<div>G</div>
<div>H</div>
<div>I</div>
<div>J</div>
```

Comment: What if the divs are of N number?

Comment: @AkhilChandran I didn't get that, could you explain?

Comment: For example, if I have 20 divs and I need to switch the styles at 2 divs?

Comment: @AkhilChandran Its a generic selector which would work for any number of `div` tags, I even added more `div` tags than in your question to demonstrate that :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you properly it should look something like this:

```css
/* style 1 */
.rows > *:nth-child(4n+1),
.rows > *:nth-child(4n+2){
 color: red;
}
/* style 2*/
.rows > *:nth-child(4n+3),
.rows > *:nth-child(4n+4){
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="rows">
    <div>1: style 1</div>
    <div>2: style 1</div>
    <div>3: style 2</div>
    <div>4: style 2</div>
    <div>5: style 1</div>
    <div>6: style 1</div>
    <div>7: style 2</div>
    <div>8: style 2</div>
</div>
```

The key to nth-child is understanding the equation for it.
Think of it as a loop, n equals the iterator of the loop and if it evaluates above 0, it will affect that element.

**4n+1**

- 4*0+1 = 1
- 4*1+1 = 5

The child elements 1 and 5 will both be targeted by the css.

**4n+2**

- 4*0+2 = 2
- 4*1+2 = 6

Here the child elements 2 and 6 will be targeted.

Adding these to together will give us 1,2,5,6 that are all targeted by the same css.

```
/* style 1 */
.rows > *:nth-child(4n+1),
.rows > *:nth-child(4n+2){
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This will solve Achieve Your Purpose....But Not much Efficient

```
const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')]

divs.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 3 == 1 || i % 3 == 2 ) el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    if (i % 4 == 2 || i % 4 == 3) el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
})
```